# how to use the props when some arguments have a certain value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, pagination, react-table

I am trying out pagination from the react-table component, and I need to use the props for multiple purposes for the pagination function. I have some values (e.g., `columns` and `data`) will be using the `useMemo()` and others will stand by (sort of). However, I get a `Syntax error: Argument name clash`, I noticed that the `...props` perhaps has perhaps overlapped with the variables, but I tried to arrange them and it didn't seem to work. What should I do in this case? The interesting part of the code could be shown below:

```
export const PaginationTable = (props, 
    {
        fetchData,
        pageCount: controlledPageCount,
        loading,
        isPaginated = true,
        ...props
    }) => {
    const columns = useMemo(() => props.columns, [])
    const data = useMemo(() => props.commits, [ props.commits ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring two variables with the same name: `props` and `...props`.

When you then do `props.columns` it's not clear which props you're referring to, hence the error.

React components take props as the first argument, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the second one where you're destructuring. I *think* you just need to remove the first `props` argument:

```js
export const PaginationTable = ({
        fetchData,
        pageCount: controlledPageCount,
        loading,
        isPaginated = true,
        ...props
    }) => {
    const columns = useMemo(() => props.columns, [])
    const data = useMemo(() => props.commits, [ props.commits ])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. What I am trying to do is to use the passed data which is columns and commits to be used in this pagination class. Those two values were fetched somewhere and stored in the memory stack, the other props don't have their value yet so i guess that's why I wanna separate them.